# TF-ICF (либо TF-IDF) без использования разреженных матриц

Tags: машинное-обучение, nlp

Прочитал недавно [статью](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221226686_TF-ICF_A_New_Term_Weighting_Scheme_for_Clustering_Dynamic_Data_Streams) про TF-ICF. Если коротко, то общий смысл в том, что в отличии от TF-IDF мы берем слово в корпусе, а не в документе. Этот способ неплох для кластеризации текстов к тому же если к нам приходит новый текст, нам не нужно пересчитывать веса слов. По идее данный способ будет работать с разреженной матрицей и далее по косинусному сходству либо евклиду или манхеттену можно найти похожие тексты.

**Проблема 1:**
Хранить разреженную матрицу *длина словаря* х *кол-во текстов в корпусе* очень и очень затратно. Особенно учитывая специфику задачи: поиск схожих абзацев текста.Т.е. каждый текст в корпусе разбивается на абзацы и ищутся похожие. С ростом абзацев объем занимаемой памяти растет и такая матрица может занимать вплоть до нескольких гигабайт.

**Проблема 2:**
Создать словарь конструкции {*слово:вес*} так же нельзя, потому что TF ICF, как и TF IDF динамичны. Т.е. для каждого предложения для одних и тех же слов веса будут разными из-за TF (напомню, что это кол-во раз которое слово встречается в документе к общему кол-ву слов в документе).

**Помогите придумать адекватный подход к поиску похожих абзацев не прибегая к созданию разреженных матриц и архиваторов типа пикл.**

P.S. 
Мои мысли на этот счет:

1. Сократить словарь согласно распределению Ципфа. Тысяч до 40, это много, но все равно не 180 тысяч как сейчас.
2. Возможно нужно использовать каким-то образом bag of words, т.е. смотреть где пересекаются тексты, в каких словах, а потом соласно тем весам что у нас есть некоторым пересечениям давать большую важность чем другим. Но как это сделать я еще тоже не придумал.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сколько я не бился над вопросом, другого варианта кроме как составить словарь ICF, а потом в потоковом режиме считать TF ICF и создавать спарс матрицу не нашел.